# Grammatical origin of a idiom

Tags: grammar-identification

> jdn. teuer zu stehen kommen

I know it means something like: jdn. viel kosten.

But my question is: What is the grammar behind this verb? How come that the verb "kommen" came with another verb "stehen"?

Comment: It means *jdn. in ferner Zukunft viel kosten*.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an expert opinion, but I consider it a contraction of

> Teuer zu Buche stehen kommen

Now "zu Buche stehen" is old-fashioned for "being an entry in a book / ledger" and "kommen" just describes the future aspect of it. All in all it means something like

> This will become an expensive entry in your ledger

Additionaly, it is common to reorder an expression so an equivalent version of this saying is

> Das kommt dir teuer zu stehen!

Comment: It's always "Das kommt *dich* teuer zu stehen!" though. Accusative, not dative.